# Help with simplification of an expression

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I was solving the residues of $f(z)e^{zt} = e^{zt}\frac{\ln(z)}{z^2+1}$ as follows:

$$\operatorname{Res}(f(z)e^{zt}, i) = \lim_{z\to i} (z-i)\frac{e^{zt}\ln(z)}{(z-i)(z+i)} = \frac{e^{it}\ln(i)}{2i}$$

and

$$\operatorname{Res}(f(z)e^{zt}, -i) = \lim_{z\to -i} (z+i)\frac{e^{zt}\ln(z)}{(z-i)(z+i)} = \frac{e^{-it}(\ln(i)+i\pi)}{-2i}$$

$$\sum \textrm{Residues} = \frac{e^{it}(\ln(i)+i\pi)}{-2i}+\frac{e^{it}\ln(i)}{2i} = \frac{-\pi e^{-it}}{2}$$

My book says the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(t)$ is it possible to simplify $\frac{-\pi e^{-it}}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(t)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "$\ln$" is the principal branch of the complex logarithm:
$$
\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=i}\left( \frac{e^{zt}\ln z}{z^2+1} \right) = \frac{e^{it}\ln i}{2i} = \frac{e^{it} i\pi}{4i} = \frac{\pi e^{it}}{4}
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=-i}\left( \frac{e^{zt}\ln z}{z^2+1} \right) = \frac{e^{-it}\ln(-i)}{-2i} = \frac{e^{-it} i\pi}{4i} = \frac{\pi e^{-it}}{4}.
$$
Finally:
$$
\frac{\pi e^{it}}{4} + \frac{\pi e^{-it}}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}\cos t.
$$

Note that $\ln(i) = \ln|i| + i\arg(i) = i\pi/2$ and $\ln(-i) = \ln|-i| + i\arg(-i) = -i\pi/2$. Here $\arg$ is the principal argument, i.e. the argument between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

Comment: So everytime i have $ln(a)$ i have to express it as $\ln|a| +iarg(a)$ ?? -Thanks